# Can't send an email in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, forms, email, post

I've put together a contact form using Django, but I can't get my `send_email` method to work.

My template for the form looks like this:

```
        <form action="/contact/auth" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <br><br>
            <input type=text class="formfields" placeholder="Name" name="name">
            <br><br>
            <input type=email class="formfields" placeholder="Email" name="contact_email">
            <br><br>
            <textarea type=text placeholder="Tell Us About Your Project" name="message"></textarea>
            <br><br>
            <input type="hidden" value="" id="num1setup" name="num1setup">
            <input type="hidden" value="" id="num2setup" name="num2setup">
            <div id="sendcontainer">
                <div id="whatis">What is &nbsp</div><div id="num1"></div><div id="plus">&nbsp + &nbsp</div><div id="num2">?</div><br>
                <div id="sumcontainer">
                    <input id="sum" type="sum" name="sum">
                    <br><br>
                </div>
                <input class="submit" type=submit value="Send">
            </div>
        </form>
```

(I realize I should probably being doing this with a Django forms class, but I'm trying to do it with a raw HTML form.)

That calls `/contact/auth` from my `urls.py` file:

```
url(r'^contact/', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
url(r'^contact/auth/', views.send_email),
```

Which calls the `send_email` method in my `views.py` file:

```
from django.views import generic
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

class ContactView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'contactpage.html'
    print("contactpage")

def send_email(request):
    print("working")
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email')
    subject = 'Message from: %s' %name
    message = request.POST.get('message')

    if subject and message and contact_email:
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, contact_email, ['example@example'], fail_silently=False)
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks')
    else:
        # In reality we'd use a form class
        # to get proper validation errors.
        return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
```

This successfully redirects to `/contact/auth` but nothing else happens after that. I've tried testing the `send_email` method, but it doesn't appear to be getting called.

I also get the following output in terminal:

[image]

Comment: Would you include Django version you are using, please?

Comment: Im using version 1.9

Comment: Okay then your problem is the following. In urls.py you need to **import views** and then you can use them. Using a string as the second argument has been deprecated since Django 1.8

Comment: I have imported views already, but you're saying the url should look like this? `url(r'^contact/auth/', views.send_email),`

Comment: That code appears to work the same as it did before.  It redirects properly, but `send_email` still doesn't get called.

Comment: Would you change the line to url(r'^contact/auth/$', views.send_email),

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but it still gives me the same issue

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I get the following red output in terminal `[03/Dec/2015 02:04:44] "POST /contact/auth HTTP/1.1" 405 0`

Comment: Did you use the **csrf_exempt** decorator? if not you need to add it to the view function

Comment: 405 response code means the method is not allowed. This means that the url does not support POST requests. Can you please add your entire view code?

Comment: Added some more code, I hope that helps.

Comment: I tried a `csrf_exempt` decorator, but the method still doesn't get called.

Comment: Can you replace url(r'^contact/', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
url(r'^contact/auth/', views.send_email), with 
url(r'^contact/$', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
url(r'^contact/auth/$', views.send_email),

Comment: I guess the issue is when you call contact/auth you are hitting ContactView. Also the curl call in the snapshot doesnt shows any trailing slash. so try /contact/auth/ and your issue will be fixed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) mentioned,

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.

The call of `/contact/auth/` first matched by `/contact`, and you did not offer the `post` function in your `ContactView`, that's why you got 405. So there are two way to fix this:

#### 1

Simply change `/contact/auth/` to `/contact123/auth/`(note the trailing slash).

I recommend you write like this:

```
url(r'^contact123/auth/', views.send_email, name='post_url'),
```

and this:

```
<form action="{% url 'post_url' %}" method="post">
...
```

This will make the change of you url pattern much more easier.

#### 2.

Add the trailing `$` like this `url(r'^contact/$', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),`.

Either two way worked fine as I tested.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the patterns. You are calling `contact/auth` which is not matching the pattern `url(r'^contact/auth/', views.send_email),` because of the trailing slash. You must use `contact/auth/`. Also just for info all post calls must have a trailing slash. That's why the 405 response is getting returned.